# Copy a file with a name that follows a pattern

Tags: linux, shell, command, cp

I need a linux command to copy a file which has a name that matches a certain pattern.

For example:

I have a file `builds/myApp_v_4.1.apk` and I want to copy it to `artifacts/myApp_v_4.1.apk`

However it can be `myApp_v_4.2.apk` or `myApp_v_4.3.apk` ...

So I'm looking for a way to copy the file that start with "myApp_v_" and ends with ".apk"

Is this dooable using the `cp` command?

thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
cp builds/myApp_v_*.apk artifacts/
```